# jQuery: Relocate absolute-position of DIV (top & left properties) on WINDOW RESIZE

Tags: jquery, html, resize, css-position, fluid

Language: **jQuery**

I have a bunch of DIVs on a page.
I'm trying to change their **absolute-position** (top/left properties) each time the window resizes (to make them proportional to the viewport, while maintaining their original layout).

- **jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/kjvSc/1/

I am successful at changing the width & height of my DIVs **(but this is not my concern, never mind that, because I am going to change font + width & height via Media Queries)**, my main concern lies at being unable to adjust these DIVs' top/left positioning.

I am almost there, but can't figure out how to make this work?

User **[Chris Barr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/79677/chris-barr)** [played with this for a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13853418/1399030), but was not able to get very far:

- **[Chris Barr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/79677/chris-barr)**'s **jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/kjvSc/4/
  What he has done was successfully & proportionally relocate/change the DIVs' **top/left** properties on window resize. I have noticed, however, that the DIVs do not initially load in their original places (as specified in their style).

Here is the Javascript that I am using:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // THIS GETS WIDTH OF CONTAINER
    var cw = $('#container').width();
    // THIS GETS ORIGINAL FONT SIZE
    var fontSize = $('.box').css('font-size');
    // THIS GETS ORIGINAL ABSOLUTE POSITION OF DIV
    var left = $('.box').css('left');

    $(".box").width(cw / 5).height(cw / 5);
    $('.box').css("font-size", fontSize / 5 + "px");
    $('.box').css("left", left / 5 + "px");

    $(window).resize(function() {
    // THIS GETS WIDTH OF CONTAINER
    var cw = $('#container').width();
    // THIS GETS ORIGINAL FONT SIZE
    var fontSize = $('.box').css('font-size');
    // THIS GETS ORIGINAL ABSOLUTE POSITION OF DIV
    var left = $('.box').css('left');

    $(".box").width(cw / 5).height(cw / 5);
    $('.box').css("font-size", fontSize / 5 + "px");
    $('.box').css("left", left / 5 + "px");
    });
});​
```

You can view it in action here - **jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/kjvSc/1/

Any help & guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was able to come up with: http://jsfiddle.net/kjvSc/3/

Here's the problem:

```
$('.box').css('font-size');
```

The above returns 16px. You can't divide 16px by 2. You have to divide 16 by 2 and then append the px.

Instead of trying to do that with jQuery, I'd recommend you use media queries in CSS. That way, your jQuery updates with height/width, and depending on what they are set to, your media query kicks in and updates the font-size.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for that clear explanation. I was thinking of using percentages for the font-size but I was not sure how to do that either. You example works when resizing the window to a smaller size, but does not adjust the font-size back once the window is readjusted to its original size. I am hoping to find a solution to this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have updated my question now, @Jiskiras, I have decided to adjust font-size & width/height properties of the elements using CSS3 media queries. Now my only concern is how to change the top/left properties of these DIVs on window resize using jQuery.

Comment: That should be easy enough. I've updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kjvSc/8/. I did use the line from Chris Barr's jsfiddle for the left code: new_left = (container / $('.box').length * i + 1) + new_width;

Comment: Thanks for the new jsFiddle @Jiskiras! It works when resizing the window, but I am a little confused about its behaviour on inital loading though. The DIVs do not position themselves according to the top/left properties specified in the CSS, that is my only problem. If there is a way for them to follow what's set in the CSS initally, then change their positions based on window resize from their original positions that would be great. But right now, they are not following what's set in the CSS. o.o

Comment: I didn't realize that was desired. Here's the updated jsfiddle that removes that functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/kjvSc/9/. The reason it was doing that is because I had trigger('resize') in the document ready function and also calling the resize function initially.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Jiskiras says, that will return a string pixel value of `16px` where you just want to get the number `16` out instead.

So, the short answer is to do this: `parseInt($('.box').css('font-size'));`

*Edit*: I tried messing with your fiddle a bit, but I didn't get very far: http://jsfiddle.net/kjvSc/4/

Comment: Thanks @Chris Barr, I see you almost had it. You seem to have gotten the absolute-positions to adjust fine, my problem lies with the font-size now. How to make them proportionate to their parent div, thanks a lot for your time! I will watch out for any possible edits you might make

Comment: Also, I have noticed in your jsFiddle that the DIVs are not initially loaded in their original absolute position . I am not sure why not, but I wanted to point that out.

Comment: I have updated my question now, @Chris Barr, I have decided to adjust font-size & width/height properties of the elements using CSS3 media queries instead. Now my only concern is how to change the **top/left properties** of these DIVs on window resize using jQuery. I wanted to use your code, but I am quite unsure why it does not initially display the elements in their original absolute-positions. But I can see that you have accomplished adjusting/relocating them proportionally on window resize.